# Set opacity with range slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to adjust the css attribute of `opacity` with a range input slider. If I have:

```
<div id="contrastFilter">&nbsp;</div>

<div id="contrastSlider">
     <input id="contrast" type="range" value="contrast" max="0.5" min="0" step="0.01"></input>
</div>
```

and I would like to change the opacity of this:

```
#contrastFilter{
  background-color:black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wfswx8m4/)

What javascript would I have to add to make this work? I would like the slider to affect the square's opacity.

Comment: Add working code snippet here or on http://jsfiddle.net please.

Comment: @SergeyDenisov added it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/sadxegLw/4/)

```js
$('#contrast').on('input', function() {
    $('#contrastFilter').css('opacity', $(this).val());
});
```

```css
#contrastFilter {
    background-color: black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    float: right;
    left: 20%;
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="contrastFilter"></div>
<div id="contrastSlider">
     <input id="contrast" type="range" value="contrast" max="0.5" min="0" step="0.01"/>
</div>
```

Comment: @ScottMyers I'm glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

First, you're going to need to revise your CSS. That `z-index` on `#contrastFilter` is going to render it above your input, making it unclickable.

Second, you'll need to add a listener to the input's change event, get the value, and update the opacity CSS of `#contrastFilter`. I recommend using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to facilitate cross-browser compliance.

CSS:

```
#contrastFilter{
  background-color:black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.2;
}

#contrastSlider {
  position: absolute;
}
```

JavaScript (using jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#contrastSlider').change(function(e) {
    var value = $(e.target).val();

    $('#contrastFilter').css('opacity', value);
  });
});
```

Forked fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lmyoz94j/